# Distance between a point on the edge of a circle to a point on a equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Equilateral triangle $ABC$ has side length 6. Let $D$ be the point on segment $BC$ such that $BD=4$. The circle passing through points $A, B, C$ intersects line $AD$ at $A$ and at another point $E$. The length of $DE$ can be expressed in simplest radical form as $\frac{A\sqrt B}C$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive integers. What is $A+B+C$?

I keep on getting $15$, but the answer key says the answer is $18$.

[image: equilateral triangle properties]

I don't know if the link to the image will work, but what I have tried so far is $R-r$ $\left(\frac{6\sqrt3}3-\frac{6\sqrt3}6\right)$. However, I realize that $R$ is calculated assuming that you are going from the center of the circle inscribed in the equilateral triangle to a point on the outside circle, and in this problem the line going through points $AD$ doesn't go through the middle of an inscribed circle. My question is what other methods should I try to find the length of $DE$ where the answer can be expressed in terms of $\frac{A\sqrt B}C$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would be helpful if you could show your efforts so far - this would make it easier for answerers to point out any errors that might have happened or confirm your solution. Please do this by making an [edit] to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Applying [Stewart's Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stewarts-theorem/#special-case-where-delta-abc-is-isosceles) in $\triangle ABC$:

$$AD^2=6^2-4\cdot2=28 \implies AD=2\sqrt{7}$$

Considering the [power of a point](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_of_a_Point_Theorem) at $D$:

$$4\cdot2=2\sqrt{7}\cdot DE \implies DE=\frac{4\sqrt{7}}{7}$$

[image]